# GridView padding in API less then 10

Tags: android, gridview

I need GridView without padding in Android API less than 10. My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
    android:background="@color/gridview_background"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:numColumns="6"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp" />
```

Result:

[image]

The red arrows show on padding. It's only in Android < 3.0 The result that I need

[image]

No padding.

P.S. Exactly the same code on android 3.0 doesn't have padding. Why is that?

Comment: Which is your targetedSDK and which is your minSDK?

Comment: My minSdkVersion is 8, targetSdkVersion is 16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can hardly find an answer =). On 2.x Android in styles is your listSelector, while its 4.x. On 4.x he probably empty, and 2.x it than that, and filled in on the barking he needs to put the attribute:

```
android: listSelector="@null"
```

Comment: You sir are a GENIUS!  How did you figure this out?!

Comment: I was using "StickyGridHeaders" from https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders, and when adding Padding, everything goes crazy inside the grid (white slots, negative scroll, etc).... After adding this attribute it works flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest compiling under the 4.x SDK to get the behavior you want, but including the devices you want to support in your minSDK.

I would *not* suggest using level 10/Android 3.0 as Honeycomb was a Tablet only incarnation of Android. You probably want to target API level 14 and have a minSDKVersion of 8-10.

Comment: My minSdkVersion is 8, targetSdkVersion is 16

Comment: And can you test it against 8 after compiling it for 16? My curses is yes and it will work as you wish